# No exe file being generated in c using cygwin

Tags: c, cygwin

I am useing cygwin for writing programs in c. However, today when I tried to compile a program in using the command

```
  gcc filename.c
```

I found out no .exe files were being generated. What may have caused this problem?

Comment: When you run that command, what happens? Is there any output? What is the potential output?

Comment: nothing happens,I mean to see the output I did have to write ./filename.exe but the trouble is that no such .exe file gets generated

Comment: GCC's binaries are called `a.out` by default (at least outside Cygwin and the like). Look up the `-o` option to change this.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with the following information.

[cygwin g++ produces no output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581388/cygwin-g-produces-no-output)

> cygcheck -s

I ran the above command and got the following warning:

```
Warning: There are multiple cygwin1.dlls on your path
```

I found the old **cygwin1.dll** in the following path:
`C:\Windows\System\cygwin1.dll`

I deleted the old **cygwin1.dll**, then exe file became to generate!

Answer (score 0):

Without a special argument, the generated executable file is called `a.out.exe` (I guess on a Windows system, possibly `aout.exe`, something like that anyway).

To make `gcc` generate an executable with a specific name you have to use the `-o` option:

```
$ gcc filename.c -o filename.exe
```

Comment: I tried that , but nothing happens I guess I should re-install cygwin

Comment: @user220789 If you list all files in the directory, there's no exe file at all? How about one only named `a.out`?